# What is the most current way to install Sharepoint Server on Windows 2003 with remote SQL?

Tags: windows-server-2003, sharepoint, installation, sharepoint-2007

There are so many options with Sharepoint that I get a little overwhelmed/confused with all the patches, upgrade options etc.

What is the most current/reliable way to install SPS on Windows 2003 in "web farm" mode with a remote SQL database?

I'm installing SPS 2007 32 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you launch the installer package for SharePoint you will want to select the "Advanced" installation option, then select the "Complete" option (do not choose "Stand-alone").

Once the installation is complete, the "SharePoint Products and Technologies Wizard" will start.  Here is where you will connect your new SharePoint to the separate SQL Server database server. Obviously you will need some kind of service account to connect to this database server.

I would recommend reading the following guide before proceeding: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=4ce750af-5564-4b92-b74b-703d4c150ba6&DisplayLang=en

HTH, Dan